# Website migration from WordPress to a static site and doing 301 redirects without access to existing site?

Tags: wordpress, 301-redirect, migration

Currently working on a project that is a hosted on WordPress that is being migrated to a static site. However I presently do not have access to the existing site as it's managed by another developer.  The concern is not the lack of having access to content as the site owner has generated very little content (reason for migration) and we were able to do this manually. Rather the concern is to do 301 redirects.

The site will not change domains but URLs such as from `example.com/?page_id=3` to `example.com/services`.  To add, the site is migrating to new server using same domain name. I thought maybe this could be done via editing permalinks prior to migration and WordPress would update automatically if configured to write on server. But if not configured (as this is not always the case) I do not have htaccess to fix it in case there are suddenly a bunch of 404 errors for every page.

Really could use some help on the best procedure to follow in this case. This is the first migration project I've worked on.

Answer (score 1):

If you migrate from a web host to another and you keep your domain name, try to update permalinks properly (via WordPress admin) after uploading the new site. WordPress should update permalinks and 301 redirect automatically URLs (for instance from `example.com/?page_id=3` to `example.com.services`).

If WordPress doesn't apply 301 redirects, you will be obliged to use an *.htaccess* file to manually apply 301 redirects from old URLs to the new ones, there is no other option to keep SEO value of your old site.

Comment: Thanks for responding Zistolen. Migrating to a new Web Host here for obvious reasons of not having access. I thought this was clear, my apologies.  In the past I've had issues where Wordpress has not "automatically redirected URLs' and had to go into the htaccess file to change this. This is what I am trying to avoid from doing as I do not have access to server. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I have edited my answer. From my experience, WordPress correctly applies 301 redirects.